# Codeigniter local host redirects to live server

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp

I downloaded the source code of a website. The website is live and working. I wanted to make some changes offline to test them first but when I go to localhost on my browser, I get redirected to live website and the changes are not being updated. Help me with this.

Comment: improved formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `application/config/config.php` page, change `base url`

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourfoldername/';
```

Comment: i tried it but it doesnt work. Still redirects me to the live server.

Comment: In  your root folder, check .htaccess file

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|static|uploads|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^esaaz.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.esaaz.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.esaaz.com [R=301,L]
what exactly do I have to change?

Comment: Use this `RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|static|uploads|robots\.txt) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L] 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$ RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$ RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 `

Comment: Thankyou for your help but its not working. Im still being redirected to live server

Comment: Backup and remove your .htaccess file code and add this code `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA] `

Comment: Clear your browser cache and run it

Answer (score 0):

Its probably

```
 $config['base_url']
```

You can find it in

> application/config/config.php

If that doesnt work, check out the .htaccess file and try to comment out rows that have 
**Redirect** in them.

You can find more info on redirecting in htaccess [here](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747748-How-can-I-redirect-and-rewrite-my-URLs-with-an-htaccess-file-)

Comment: base url didnt solve the issue. What exactly should i change in .htaccess file?